# No output from serial monitor

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to convert a sensor value to binary to be stored in a small char array (`tbuf`) and concatenate the small arrays into one bigger array. Ultimately, I want to send the big array (`pbuf`) filled with 7, 10-bit values over serial with `Serial.write()`. This is the code that I've tried so far:

```c++
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      int s = 251;
      char pbuf[78];
      char tbuf[11];
      itoa(s, tbuf, 2);
      strcat(pbuf, tbuf);
      Serial.println(pbuf);
  }
  Serial.end();
}
```

It doesn't output the permanent buffer (`pbuf`), or anything, to the serial monitor. My output to the serial monitor is nothing.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get an output from code similar to this.

Comment: Is there any data that the `Serial.available()` shows is available to read? In other words have you typed anything? https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/available

Comment: `pbuf` is uninitialized and why are you calling `Serial.end();`?

Comment: So the stuff in the if serial.available() branch won't run unless I am already sending something over serial to the Arduino?

Comment: Can you explain how pbuf is uninitialized? I'm calling Serial.end(), because I only want to do the concatenation once

Comment: Reading the documentation on `Serial.available()` it returns the number of characters that are available to be read from the serial device. If there are no characters available to be read then it returns zero (0). As long as it returns zero you will not see the `Serial.println()` executed. Try commenting out the if statement and just doing prints.

Comment: If you don't want it to loop then don't put the code in the function called loop.

Comment: On the Arduino the `loop()` function is called periodically. This allows you to write a program that (1) sets up the environment in `setup()` and (2) performs sensor reads and take actions periodically in `loop()`. So `setup()` is called once when the device powers up or is reset and then `loop()` is called multiple times until the device is powered down or reset. Check out the tutorials that come with Sketch. See also https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink

Comment: See this video tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nL34zDTPkcs  Discussion of `setup()` and `loop()` begins around 8:40 with a sample program.

Comment: This question is really too broad as you provide some basic requirements are then asking for a design with some code. However there are a number of questions that you have not addressed. What kind of sensors and what is the interface to the sensors and the data type and how is the sensor data obtained? What is the format of the data to be sent over serial (10 bit values don't fit in 8 bit chars)? There are many other questions that need to be answered.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `Serial.end()` in function `loop()`. Your code runs one time `Serial.begin()` and if your Serial is not available then you are calling only `Serial.end()`.
Maybe you could try this approach:

```cxx
int varA =0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    varA = Serial.parseInt(); //or   Serial.parseFloat();
    Serial.println(varA);
  }
}
```